Pandas to_datetime function converts NaT to 1970-01-01
I'm working on a Python program that imports a CSV file into an SQL table, I need to maintain the integrity of the data and ensure it adheres to the specified schema without alterations.
Some of the date columns values are set to NaT, but when I execute the to_datetime function It transforms them into the default 1970-01-01.
Whereas I need it to stay at NaT because I want to keep the value as it is.
data[column]= pd.to_datetime(data[column],errors='coerce')

Example of data :
    COLUMN_A
0      NaT
1      NaT
2      NaT

The output in the SQL table is :
    COLUMN_A
0      1970-01-01
1      1970-01-01
2      1970-01-01

Is there a way to expose this column type as DATE while maintaining the integrity of my data ?

could you add some info on how you create the SQL table?

@FObersteiner  I'm loading into a bigQuery table, the solution is actually to load directly from the csv file instead of transforming it into a DataFrame object.
Using the method : client.load_table_from_file

ok, now your solution sounds more appropriate. Just wanted to point out that pd.to_datetime is likely not the issue here; the problem more likely is that "NaT" is pandas-specific. If something downstream of you pd.DataFrame (such as the bq table) cannot represent it, it might default to something like Unix time 0, which is 1970-01-01.

Ok after looking around, the solution is to load the file directly instead of transforming it into a DataFrame object. That way the data integrity is insured.
